# What is the best practice in regards to paths while working in different OS (Xamirin/Android, Windows, Web) environments?

Tags: c#, android, architecture, path, xamarin

I am currently working on a simple Xamarin-Android application which is re-using the C# class libraries that were built in .NET 4.5. These libraries are common between Android and Windows and Web Services currently.

following are the paths pointing to text resource file(s),

**Windows Desktop:** AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\resource.txt

**Windows Service:** AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"bin\resource.txt

**Android:** "/data/data/My.App.Folder/resource.txt" (Also in xamarin what is the way to get application folder? currently AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is yielding null)

The issue is the paths are different in different environments.

What would be the best practice in order to solve this issue?

Comment: Take a look at [Platform.VirtualFileSystem](https://github.com/platformdotnet/Platform.VirtualFileSystem/).

Comment: What in Platform.VirtualFileSystem would give OP the 3 different paths he quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On android apps deploy as APK. You can't access any files deployed with the app directly through the filesystem (everything is in the APK). You need to work with embedded resources

Answer (score 0):

If your rule is "my text resource files are in the same directory as the app" then this might be what you want:

```
new FileInfo( 
        new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath 
        )
    .Directory
    .FullName
```

Although in that case, can you not include the text files in your dll as embedded resources?

Either way; I don't think the Framework or the runtime is going to tell **you** what your paths are; you will have to tell it. So I'd create a config setting / config transform for each deployment platform.